# How to iterate over Array List and modify elements inside the object in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, list

I have an Array List `List<CatchItem.CatchesItem> catchesItems = new ArrayList<>()`; that contains the following objects:

```
[
   {"amount":1,"condition":0.0,"time":"Feb 17, 2021 05:10:42 PM"}, 
   {"amount":4,"condition":1.0,"time":"Feb 17, 2021 05:10:48 PM"}, 
   {"amount":5,"condition":2.0,"time":"Feb 18, 2021 05:10:54 PM"}
]
```

To iterate the list I can by following:

```java
    for (int i = 0; i < catchesItems.size(); i++) {
        catchesItems.get(i);
    }
```

However, how can I check if the object in the list contains a timestamp for today's and if it contains then modify the amount
element in the object by appending with the new value, if not then leave it as it is?

Comment: What have you tried and what are you having problems doing?

Comment: And also include the code for `CatchesItem` (at least the instance variables).

Comment: I'd think that you can get the `time` value out of the current list element by using something like `catchesItems.get(i).time` and then compare it using before() or after() methods of timestamp class. Having definition of `CatchesItem` class would have been helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that class `CatchesItem` has `time` field defined as `LocalDateTime`, the check for today's timestamp may be implemented as follows:

```java
import java.time.*;

// ...
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
for (CatchesItem item : items) {
    if (today.equals(item.getTime().toLocalDate())) {
        item.setAmount(item.getAmount() + 5); // add some value to amount
    }
}
items.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output (for the input data as of Feb 18)

```
CatchesItem(amount=1, condition=0.0, time=2021-02-17T17:10:42)
CatchesItem(amount=4, condition=1.0, time=2021-02-17T17:10:48)
CatchesItem(amount=10, condition=2.0, time=2021-02-18T17:10:54)
```

Comment: Thank you. It does what I needed :)